# Playlist player with Spotify Web API

Tags: php, html, spotify

I just find this 
    https://github.com/possan/webapi-player-example

And I've been searching for something like this but with an specific playlist in my site

Want I want is:

1. Login in Spotify like the example( http://lab.possan.se/thirtify )
2. After that be able to play my music(playlist) like the example in the same tab with Full Length in, not open a new page with spotify player.

I have the Client ID, Client Secret, Redirect URIs.

Is it posible? I have no idea about how to make it

I've been trying with the [embed](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/widgets/examples/) code but when the user login open a new page with the spotify player, I want to redirect to the same page with the playlist.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Use programming to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > After that be able to play my music(playlist) like the example in the same tab with Full Length in, not open a new page with spotify player.

Streaming full length tracks over the web is not supported by Spotify's Web API.  That's why the example application uses the 30 second audio files. Streaming tracks is however possible using the [iOS](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-ios-sdk/) and [Android SDKs](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-android-sdk/).